# Magento 2 add Ui-comopnent into not Ui form

Tags: magento2, category, uicomponent

I need to add **categories tree** like this one [image]

into Magento target Rule tab - [image]

> the problem is - magento target rule edit form is not a ui-form.

Can I add this with something like `$form->addElement()` or similar method?